# saving JSON object in iOS

Tags: objective-c, json, ios

I use SBJsonParser for parsing a large json response I query from a server. I'd like to use a timestamp approach to know when I actually have to re-obtain and re-parse all the data again, so I'd like to know how I can save my data for those times I don't need to request the large JSON package to refresh my data.

I'm thinking I should be using the NSCoding protocol and archiving roughly like the following:

```
// alloc nsdata obj
NSMutableData *data = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];

// create archiver
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data] autorelease];  

// archive whiteboard
[archiver encodeObject:mSaveData forKey:@"Data"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
```

but is there a simple way to encode this JSON object that is really an NSArray of NSDictionaries, or do I have to meticulously encode each field within this object?

Maybe there is a simpler way altogether, like saving the json object itself as a string (before it is parsed with the objectWithData method) and re-parsing it each time the app loads and wants to use the local copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data you want to save are just NSArrays, NSDictionaries, and presumably things like NSStrings and NSNumbers, I don't see why you need to "meticulously encode each field".  The way you did it with NSKeyedArchiver is valid, and you don't need any further code to save.  Some other options:

- Use `+[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:]`.
- Use SBJSON to turn the data back into JSON and store the JSON string as UTF-8 data.
- Save it out as a plist using `+[NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:format:errorDescription:]`.

Comment: Thanks, but my understanding was that the object being encoded would have to implement the NSCoding protocol and then essentially call encode___ methods (in the encodeWithCoder: method) for each saved piece of data.  Are you saying I can simply use the encodeObject:forKey: method and pass in the NSArray, or alternatively pass the NSArray as the root object in the archiveRootObject:toFile: method (without going over each field) and it will just save all the data even when it is a nested array of dictionaries and arrays etc?

Comment: Pass the NSArray as the root object, and you should be good to go. When you decode it, you get back the array as the root object.

Comment: ok. this is because the NSArray object natively implements the nscoding protocol as needed?

Comment: Yes; any object that adopts the `NSCoding` protocol (as you can tell from the API reference) can be encoding using NSKeyedEncoder. The only time you have to implement `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` is if you want to be able to encode one of your own classes using NSKeyedEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

AsiHTTP allows you to cache your requests. It implements the features that you need